# Zsh, splitting the expansion of %~

Tags: zsh, string

I'm at my wits end with this. I'm using zsh and trying to simply split the expansion of `%3~` on the `/` character. This works fine with the expansion of `$(pwd)` and `$PWD` - both of which are also path-like strings.

I'm trying to split a string using the following code `("${(@s./.)a}")` - where a is either `a=$(pwd)` or `a=%3~`. Again this code works with `pwd`, but not `%3~`.

I'm still a bit new to shell scripting -- but as far as I understand it, there should be no discrepancy. No matter what I do, I cannot get the expansion of `%~` to split properly. Things I've tried:

```
# Ran from /home/me/code
a=%3~
b=$(pwd)
c=$PWD
d="/test/1/2"

e=$(echo "$a")
f="/$a"

echo $a # ~/code
echo $b # /home/me/code
echo $c # /home/me/code
echo $d # /test/1/2
echo $e # ~/code
echo $f # /~/code

("${(@s./.)a}") # ~/code
("${(@s./.)b}") # home me code
("${(@s./.)c}") # home me code
("${(@s./.)d}") # test 1 2
("${(@s./.)e}") # ~/code
("${(@s./.)f}") # /~/code
```

I'm actually starting to think that zsh is just intentionally inconsistent. I'm sure I'm just missing something, though. I've also tried `("${(ps./.)a}")`, because as I read it that should do the same. I've also tried IFS-based splitting, setting `IFS="/"`. Again, works for normal strings - does not work for `%~`. **???**

**EDIT**: For the sake of completeness, this is within a .zsh-theme file where. I suppose maybe this matters? I'm technically not the one executing it (it's being ran by oh-my-zsh), so maybe something weird is happening at that level.

Comment: `echo $a` should by default output `%3~`, not `~/code`.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Oddly not - which is part of the reason this is so confusing to me. It outputs ```~/code``` and I can echo it just like any other string. Only splitting (and I'm sure other things I haven't tried) end up failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use an prompt escape outside of the context where prompt escapes are normally evaluated. so the variable contains the string `%3~`, you attempt to split the string `%3~` resulting in `%3~` and i am assuming it is later assigned to `PS1`/`PROMPT` which zsh then expands `%3~`.

If you would like to perform parameter expansions and have the string `%3~` treated like a prompt escape you can use the parameter expansion flag `%` like so `${(%)a}`

Comment: thanks! It worked. For anyone interested, [here's](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) a good resource for understanding parameter expansion a little better. I'm still unclear as to _why_ prompt parameter expansion had to be used when I could just echo parameter and get the value. Oh well - ```("${(@s./.)${(%)b}}")```, where ```b=%3~``` works.

Comment: because you don't get the value by "just by using echo" it is a string that the shells treats special when drawing your prompt.